# Cannot change background color in print stylesheet

Tags: css, drupal-7

I'm trying to make a print stylesheet that will change the background color of a div on a drupal page. But when I'm printing, it doesn't change the background color (Yes, my browser does print background colors). The relevant part of my CSS looks like this:

```
@media print {
 #footer-wrapper {background: #fff;}
}
```

I have tried both with and without the `@media print` block and I tried both `background` and `background-color` but none of this changes the color when printing. I also tried to hide the div (because I just don't want it to show in the print). When I change the css of the regular page, it disappears there, but still shows up in the print.

The reason I want to do this is when I try to print, the footer will try to occupy 100% of the printed page.

Comment: You're trying to change the background colour to white, and saying it doesn't print on white paper?!

Comment: The default colour is grey. I'm trying to change it to white, so it doesn't print.

Comment: Change it to red to test the CSS. Does that work? I'm guessing the printer/browser thinks that white doesn't need to be printed (even though I understand your logic as to why)

Comment: @Robbie That does not work either.

Comment: OK - just to rule out "is it my CSS" issue, try adding a border or change something else and get it to show when you print. If that fails, it doesn't look like it's picking up css; if it works then... hmmm. Also, does it work in another browser?

Comment: @Robbie for some reason it works in Internet Explorer now. The only problem is that IE does not recognize the page breaks I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the css file that set the colors was protected in some way. It would make this css file always have priority. I changed the color to white in the Drupal UI, and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try "printing some part of the page"

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't see you page but is your "@media pint" statement possibly inside another stylesheet which is set to media="screen"?

If so take it out of that and simply create another stylesheet set to media="print" with your rile in there. You then won;t even need the "@media print" bit.

Comment: It is set to be print. I copied the `@media print` part from another website to place some other CSS tags in.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site or place all your code in a fiddle?